# Session Flow in LUIS

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Does LUIS or MS BOT framework offer a facility where you can visualize the session flow? If yes, can you please guide me on how to get it done? I have searched all the documents, but can not find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and read around LUIS and bot framework, there is no such facility to visualize the session flow